# Get 2-2 record from collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I have multiple records in same collection with different-2 status. I want 2-2 record of every status.

**Sample collection**:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Record1",
    "status": "pending"
  }, {
    "title": "Record2",
    "status": "ready"
}, {
    "title": "Record3",
    "status": "ready"
}, {
    "title": "Record4",
    "status": "ready"
}, {
    "title": "Record5",
    "status": "pending"
}, {
    "title": "Record6",
    "status": "pending"
}, {
    "title": "Record7",
    "status": "pending"
}, {
    "title": "Record8",
    "status": "pending"
}, {
    "title": "Record9",
    "status": "pending"
}, {
    "title": "Record10",
    "status": "pending"
}, {
    "title": "Record11",
    "status": "ready"
}]
```

**Expected result**:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Record1",
        "status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "title": "Record5",
        "status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "title": "Record2",
        "status": "ready"
    }, 
    {
        "title": "Record3",
        "status": "ready"
    }
]
```

Comment: In your question, can you explain what you mean by different-2 and 2-2? And what logic produces that expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
db.test.insert(
{
record:[{title:"r1",status:"pending"}, 
        {title:"r2",status:"ready"},
        {title:"r3",status:"pending"},
        {title:"r4",status:"pending"},
        {title:"r5",status:"ready"},
        {title:"r6",status:"ready"}
    ]
}
)

db.test.aggregate(
    [
        {$unwind:"$record"},
        {$group:{_id:"$record.status",titles:{$addToSet:"$record.title"}}},
        {$project:{_id:0,status:"$_id",records:{$slice:["$titles",2]}}},
        {$unwind:"$records"}
    ]
)
```

Result:

```
{ "status" : "pending", "records" : "r1" }
{ "status" : "pending", "records" : "r3" }
{ "status" : "ready", "records" : "r5" }
{ "status" : "ready", "records" : "r2" }
```

Comment: I am using laravel and i am getting error

MongoResultException in Collection.php line 42:
localhost:27017: exception: invalid operator '$slice'

Comment: My code is 

$res = Users::raw()->aggregate([

      ['$group' =>
          [
           '_id' => '$status',
           'titles' => [ '$addToSet' => '$first_name' ] 
           ]
      ],

      ['$project' => 
       ['_id' => 0,'status' => '$_id', 'records' => [ '$slice' => ['$titles',2] ] ] 
      ],

    ]);

Comment: Whats your mongoDB version?

Comment: I have updated my mongo version and its working perfectly.
You are awesome
Thanks